# jQuery Mobile app how to reinitiate

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-maps, intel-xdk

This is possible a very silly question, but I'm learning as I go. I developed a simple single page jQuery Mobile/PhoneGap app using Intel XDK that create a Map, place a marker in the current location. Then it allows to to add markers, calculate route, distance,etc. All that works perfectly. But, now, how do I "restart/ reset" the app so it goes to "initial state"? Using Google Maps's documentation, I was able to delete the markers, etc. But I can't figure out how to go back to the beginning. I added a button that when clicked triggers a function:

```
function reStartPage() {
//location.reload();
//navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

When I try location.reload(), the app reloads indeed, but the pages blinks as expected. On the other hand when I use navigator.app.exitApp(), it "kills" the application, but it doesn't re-initiate it. What options do I have?

Somewhere someone suggested something like:

```
$.mobile.loadPage("#home", {
allowSamePageTransition : true,
transition : 'slide',
changeHash : true,
reloadPage : true
 });

$.mobile.changePage("#home", {
allowSamePageTransition : true,
transition : 'slide',
 changeHash : true,
reloadPage : true
});
```

But that doesn't work either. Please let me know if more details are needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refresh the map with:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(my_map, 'resize');
```

Comment: Thanks @mboeckle, but that won't do it. Regarding google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference documentation "Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size". I'm not resizing the map (or div). I just want to "restart" the app. If I'm missing something, please let me know.